# Actions on Google 'Get Sign In' Helper

Tags: oauth-2.0, actions-on-google, google-authentication

I am using the following code in my Actions on Google application:

```
app.intent('Get Sign In', async (conv, params, signin) => {
  if (signin.status !== 'OK') {
    return conv.close(`Let's try again next time.`);
  }
  const color = conv.data[Fields.COLOR];
  const {email} = conv.user;
  if (!conv.data.uid && email) {
    try {
      conv.data.uid = (await auth.getUserByEmail(email)).uid;
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.code !== 'auth/user-not-found') {
        throw e;
      }
      // If the user is not found, create a new Firebase auth user
      // using the email obtained from the Google Assistant
      conv.data.uid = (await auth.createUser({email})).uid;
    }
  }
  if (conv.data.uid) {
    conv.user.ref = db.collection('users').doc(conv.data.uid);
  }
  conv.close(`I saved ${color} as your favorite color for next time.`);
});
```

I've been looking through the docs, but can't find any explanation about the 'params' argument of the function? How do I pass values to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the params object if you are using dialogflow. For example, if you use entities in Dialogflow you can retrieve them through params object in the intent handler.

> If you are using Dialogflow, you can access the parameter values via the params variable.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejsv2/overview)

More info about the param object itself can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejsv2/overview#access_parameters_and_contexts).

Comment: Thanks man! I should maybe rephrase my question:
I trigger a 'new SignIn()' from my code. Then the OAuth procedure starts. Afterwards, the 'Get Sign In' intent is triggered. Is it possible to add parameters to the 'Get Sign in' dynamically via code?

Comment: As far as I know that is not possible, the only information that you get from the response of a new SignIn() event is the signIn object where you can check the status of the signIn and act upon it. I've only seen the params object work to get params from an normal intent that triggers on user input. Not on a sign in event like Get Sign In. I also see nothing about adding to the params object in the signInHelper docs.